# transformations on sparkSQL that similar to DataFrame of the python Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

What should I do if I want to do some transformations on a Spark DataFrame and the transformations should be performed similarly to the method of pandas' `DataFrame.apply()`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object SparkSQLTransform {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()
    val peopleDF = sparkSession.read.json("resources/people.json")
    peopleDF.show()
    /*
    +---+-------+------+
    |age|   name|   sex|
    +---+-------+------+
    | 25|Michael|female|
    | 30|   Andy|female|
    | 19| Justin|  male|
    | 39|  Alice|female|
    +---+-------+------+
     */

    //if there is some common operations act as the pandas.DataFrame.apply() method, which
    //can got the result below:
    /*
    +---+-------+------+
    |age|   name|   sex|
    +---+-------+------+
    | 25|Michael|0|
    | 30|   Andy|0|
    | 19| Justin| 1|
    | 39|  Alice|0|
    +---+-------+------+
     */
  }

}

the content of people.json :
{"name":"Michael", "age":25, "sex": "female"}
{"name":"Andy", "age":30, "sex":"female"}
{"name":"Justin", "age":19, "sex": "male"}
{"name":"Alice", "age": 39, "sex": "female"}
```

Comment: I have edit my question and look forward to your reply